# classpathentry for lazy val project

Tags: java, sbt, typesafe-activator, sbteclipse, lagom

in [***defining service***](http://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.0.x/java/LagomBuild.html#defining-a-service) description in lagom documents, I have defined a service as follow:

```
lazy val userApi = project("user-api")
    .settings(
    version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT",
    libraryDependencies += lagomJavadslApi
    )
lazy val userImpl = project("user-impl")
    .enablePlugins(LagomJava)
    .settings(
        version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT",
        libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        lagomJavadslPersistence,
        lagomJavadslTestKit
        )
    )
.settings(lagomForkedTestSettings: _*)
.dependsOn(userApi)
```

but on build with `activator` or `sbt` the directory structure `user-api/src/main/java` or `user-impl/src/main/java` is not getting created.

Comment: Works for me. What happens if you start sbt with your build file? Do you get an error message? Please post the rest of your build.sbt and also check if you have the lagom-sbt-plugin in your project/plugins.sbt

Comment: Thanks it is fixed, I do not know why, but when I changed addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0") to 3.0.0  the directory structure generated correctly